# Magento Admin Grid Issues

Tags: php, xml, magento

Getting extremely confused with an adminhtml module i'm trying to write!

Effectively I have the indexcontroller written and working, and i'm trying to call a grid block:

```
$<?php

class MyTuxedo_OutOfStock_Block_Adminhtml_Web_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
   public function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->setId('OOSGrid');
  $this->setDefaultSort('OOS_id');
  $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
  $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
}

protected function _prepareCollection()
{
  $collection = Mage::getModel('MyTuxedo/OutOfStock')->getCollection();
  $this->setCollection($collection);
  return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
  $this->addColumn('category_name', array(
      'header'    => Mage::helper('OutOfStock')->__('Category'),
      'align'     =>'right',
      'width'     => '50px',
      'index'     => 'web_id',
  ));

  $this->addColumn('sku', array(
      'header'    => Mage::helper('OutOfStock')->__('SKU'),
      'align'     =>'left',
      'index'     => 'title',
  ));

/*
  $this->addColumn('quantity', array(
 'header'    => Mage::helper('OutOfStock')->__('Quantity Available'),
'width'     => '150px',
'index'     => 'content',
  ));
*/

  $this->addColumn('Backorder allowed', array(
      'header'    => Mage::helper('OutOfStock')->__('Status'),
      'align'     => 'left',
      'width'     => '80px',
      'index'     => 'status',
      'type'      => 'options',
      'options'   => array(
          1 => 'Enabled',
          2 => 'Disabled',
      ),
  ));

    $this->addColumn('action',
        array(
            'header'    =>  Mage::helper('OutOfStock')->__('Action'),
            'width'     => '100',
            'type'      => 'action',
            'getter'    => 'getId',
            'actions'   => array(
                array(
                    'caption'   => Mage::helper('OutOfStock')->__('Edit'),
                    'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/edit'),
                    'field'     => 'id'
                )
            ),
            'filter'    => false,
            'sortable'  => false,
            'index'     => 'stores',
            'is_system' => true,
    ));

$this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('OutOfStock')->__('CSV'));
$this->addExportType('*/*/exportXml', Mage::helper('OutOfStock')->__('XML'));

  return parent::_prepareColumns();
}


 public function getRowUrl($row)
{
  return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $row->getId()));
}
```

I am using a controller to call the method through:

```
<?php
class MyTuxedo_OutOfStock_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('OutOfStock/adminhtml_OutOfStock'));
    $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Layout file consists of the following:

```
<?xml version=“1.0??>
<layout version=“0.1.0?>
  <OutOfStock_index_index>
    <reference name=“content”>
  <block type=“OutOfStock/adminhtml_OutOfStock“ name=“OutOfStock“ />
</reference>
</OutOfStock_index_index>
</layout>
```

And finally the block base file:

```
 <?php
class MyTuxedo_OutOfStock_Block_Adminhtml_OutOfStock extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
public function __construct()
{
 $this->_controller = ‘adminhtml_OutOfStock’;
 $this->_blockGroup = ‘OutOfStock’;
 $this->_headerText = Mage::helper(‘OutOfStock’)->__(‘Item Manager’);
     $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper(‘OutOfStock’)->__(‘Add Item’);
 parent::__construct();
  }
}
```

I have tried everything and anything to get the grid to show on the backend, it just absolutely refuses to work. Running echo's in the indexcontroller works fine, I have even called a CMS static block fine from within the controller, just calling the block itself refuses to work.

Has anyone got any suggestions? Can post the config.xml as well if needed just didn't want to bloat the question too much!

Thanks!!

Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>  
<modules> 
   <MyTuxedo_OutOfStock>    
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    </MyTuxedo_OutOfStock>   
 </modules>  
 <adminhtml>   
  <layout>    
    <updates>      
      <outofstock>        
        <file>OutOfStock.xml</file>      
      </outofstock>      
  </updates>   
 </layout>        
 <acl>        
 <resources>    
        <admin>     
         <children>      
              <outofstock>    
                    <title>Out of Stock Items</title>      
                  <children>                        
             <OutOfStock>     
                     <title>Out of Stock Items</title>                      
          </OutOfStock>                   
       </children>          
          </outofstock>             
     </children>      
      </admin> 
       </resources>  
  </acl>   
  </adminhtml>  
  <global>
  <models>
<outofstock>
    <class>MyTuxedo_OutOfStock_Model</class>
</outofstock> 
  </models>      
  <helpers>     
   <outofstock>   
         <class>MyTuxedo_OutOfStock_Helper</class>    
    </outofstock>   
  </helpers> 
<blocks>
<outofstock>
<class>MyTuxedo_OutOfStock_Block</class>
</outofstock>
</blocks> 
</global>
  <admin>
    <routers>
        <MyTuxedo_OutOfStock>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>MyTuxedo_OutOfStock</module>
                <frontName>OutOfStock</frontName>
            </args>
        </MyTuxedo_OutOfStock>
    </routers>
 </admin>
 </config>
```

I've actually changed the configuration scope, however i'm still getting:

```
 2012-06-12T09:43:35+00:00 ERR (3): 
 exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type:       MyTuxedo_OutOfStock_Block_Adminhtml_Nostock' in /chroot/home/mytuxedo   /developer.mytuxedo.co.uk/html/app/Mage.php:550
 Stack trace:
 #0 /chroot/home/mytuxedo/developer.mytuxedo.co.uk/html/includes/src/__default.php(24835): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
 #1 /chroot/home/mytuxedo/developer.mytuxedo.co.uk/html/includes/src/__default.php(24777): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('OutOfStock/Admi...', Array)
 #2 /chroot/home/mytuxedo/developer.mytuxedo.co.uk/html/app/code/local/MyTuxedo/OutOfStock/controllers/Adminhtml/OutOfStockController.php(7): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('OutOfStock/Admi...')
 #3 /chroot/home/mytuxedo/developer.mytuxedo.co.uk/html/includes/src/__default.php(12068): MyTuxedo_OutOfStock_Adminhtml_OutOfStockController->indexAction()
 #4 /chroot/home/mytuxedo/developer.mytuxedo.co.uk/html/includes/src/__default.php(16116): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
 #5 /chroot/home/mytuxedo/developer.mytuxedo.co.uk/html/includes/src/__default.php(15713): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
 #6 /chroot/home/mytuxedo/developer.mytuxedo.co.uk/html/includes/src/__default.php(17973): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
 #7 /chroot/home/mytuxedo/developer.mytuxedo.co.uk/html/app/Mage.php(596): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
 #8 /chroot/home/mytuxedo/developer.mytuxedo.co.uk/html/index.php(97): Mage::run('', 'store')
 #9 {main}
```

Comment: In your index, do var_dump($this->getLayout()->createBlock('OutOfStock/adminhtml_OutOfStock')); and see if this gives you the block object. I'm wondering if your class names or lookups may be slightly out.

Comment: Can you post your config.xml, just to check the block aliases. Also try different casing, as Magento does do some case conversion on lookup names.

Comment: I think the casing is the problem, in confix.xml you have outofstock but in your lookup you're using OutOfStock, try outofstock/adminhtml_OutOfStock in your layout / index controller

Comment: I've tried following a tutorial from the flat up, the tutorial version gives me the same error. I'm getting:

exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: MyTuxedo_OutOfStock_Block_Adminhtml_Nostock' in /chroot/home/mytuxedo/developer.mytuxedo.co.uk/html/app/Mage.php:550
Stack trace:
#0 /chroot/home/mytuxedo/developer.mytuxedo.co.uk/html/includes/src/__default.php(24835): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /chroot/home/mytuxedo/developer.mytuxedo.co.uk/html/includes/src/__default.php(24777): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('OutOfStock/Admi...', Array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, hadn't noticed the compilation process was switched on (Have no idea why I had switched it on?!). - Hours wasted, for those with class not found make sure you check the compiler before debugging!!!